# simple type mismatch error

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I was trying to write some simple method `toList`...

```
trait Stream[+A] {

  def uncons: Option[(A, Stream[A])]

  def isEmpty: Boolean = uncons.isEmpty

  def toList[A]: List[A] = this.uncons match {
    case Some((h,t)) => h::t.toList
    case None => List()
  }

}
```

however, this results in the following error:

```
type mismatch; found : x$1.type (with underlying type A) required: A
```

I don't understand why this code doesn't work. Probably I am missing something very obvious :(

Answer (score 5):

The problem is in your `toList` method definition.
By doing:

```
def toList[A]: List[A] = this.uncons match { ... }
```

You are actually defining a new type `A` in which your method is parameterized.
Just declare the method as:

```
def toList: List[A] = this.uncons match { ... }
```

and you are good to go (this definition would be using the same `A` defined in the class)